# Access media collection with metadata over DLNA

Tags: media-player, dlna, kodi

I've got a big media collection on my main PC, and would like to be able to watch it on different devices (TV, laptop), without having to manually copy files around. A good way to do this seems to be via DLNA. I managed to get a DLNA server running (TVMOBiLi and XBMC both work), and can view my files from other DLNA players (is that the right term?), specifically XBMC. However, it's still quite complicated to add the server, browse to the subdirectory (usually something complicated like `My Content/Videos/TV Shows/S - U/blah/Season 03`). If it's like that, I could just 'share' the folder with the OS's file sharing function instead.

What I'd like to have is to have the videos (and music) integrated into the client's library, so that they show up with all the metadata they have on the server (season, episode, artwork, etc.), and not just as filenames. Is there a way to make this possible with XBMC or another program? Do you have software recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

When you add new media (source) in XBMC it should scrape all of your files and automatically download the meta-data from the internet.

http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Video_library/Adding_media_sources

This will include description, any covers/artwork etc. From your question it seems like you are just browsing a shared folder where your media is - rather than adding it to your library?

Answer (score 0):

He mentioned that the files are on a DLNA server. XBMC itself will not scrape files that are hosted on a dlna server, only files that are stored locally (or can be accessed as a locally stored file)

The easiest way most people find to run media off a server and still have metadata (posters and descriptionts), and be able to play it on devices other than a computer, is to use Plex.

Supposedly serviio can be used to scrape if you're using XBMC, but I've never been a fan of serviio and have always had trouble doing one thing or another..